# SSIS: Enabling transactions causes database connection to fail

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ssis

I have a package that I'm using to load records from a CSV file into a table. It has three elements in the control flow:

- Truncate table
- Load File into Table
- Verify that there are records on the table after the load or raise an error

The idea is to have a single transaction on the package, so if the load of elements fails or the file was empty then the transaction is rolled back and the table isn't truncated.

To enable the transaction I just go to the package properties and set **TransactionOption=Required**, then I just try to execute the package and get this error while trying to execute the first element (The SQL task that tries to truncate the table):

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Failed to acquire connection "Database
>   Connection". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not
>   have the right permissions on this connection.

If I just go back and change the TransactionOption property of the package to the default (Supported) then the package executes correctly but if there's an error there's no rollback.

I am using ADO.NET to connect to a SQL Server DB.

Any idea of what am I doing wrong? Is this the correct way to use transactions or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: May be this question of SO, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568183/transactionoption-in-ssis might help you. Not sure though weather it worked for OP or not.

Comment: Is 'Database Connection' your Excel or SQL Server connection? Are you loading data into SQL Server? It helps if these things are described explicitly so we don't have to assume things.

Comment: @JackLock Yep, hadn't seen that question. The second option kind of works but seems like a hack to me, and transactions should be supported. In the end I went to use a temporary table and when it has records I just truncate the original table and move the data. Also a trick which means it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: @ElectricLlama Actually I thought it was clear enough. I do mention that I am using ADO.NET to connect to a SQL Server DB and the input is a CSV file, don't know what else would you like to know.

Comment: Sorry, don't mean to be a troll. I missed the but about the SQL Server DB - I see it now, my mistake. I know it seems obvious, but your connection 'Database Connection' mentioned in your error message, it is probably the connection to your database, but it saves a lot of hassle if you just verify it, otherwise everyone makes assumptions that might be incorrect.

Comment: I had the same problem. I found a solution here - http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/09/ssis-transactions-with-tsql.html

Note the comment at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but I had the same problem as you - the package works fine until I set one of the containers transaction's option to **TransactionOption=Required**
From what I understand, this might be related to Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC) service not being started **on the SQL server**.

When I had this issue I checked if MSDTC is started on the machine on which I was running the package - it was. Sadly, I couldn't access the SQL server to check the same thing.

But, following these steps on the machine running the package solved the problem:

On Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista:

1. Click **Start**, click **Run**, and type **dcomcnfg** to launch the Component Services Management console.
2. Click to expand **Component Services** and click to expand **Computers**.
3. Click to expand My Computer, click to expand **Distributed Transaction Coordinator**, right-click **Local DTC**, and click **Properties**.
4. Click the **Security** tab of the **Local DTC Properties** dialog.

In that dialog box, I had to **enable** "**Network DTC Access**" and also "**Allow Inbound**" and "**Allow Outbound**".

Sources:

[msdn forum about this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/abeff835-f379-41cb-9e9b-a78a3d27a637/implementing-transaction-in-ssis-package-execute-sql-task-error-failed-to-acquire-connection?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

[msdn article about troubleshooting Problems with MSDTC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561924.aspx)