# Restricting SSIS Transaction to a single connection manager

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ssis, distributed-transactions

I have a fairly complex ETL with two Connection Managers:

- InputDatabase
- OutputDatabase

InputDatabase is read-only, with `IsolationLevel=ReadUncommited` on the ETL. I'm currently using `TransactionOption=Required` on my container to enable rollback on failure.

**Is there a way to only use transactions on OutputDatabase, since they are not necessary on InputDatabase?** While the current implementation works, it requires setting up Distributed Transaction Coordinator on a server that should not need it, along with opening firewalls and ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be beyond the intent of the `TransactionOption` support.

To use transactions on a single data source:

1. Set the data source to `RetainSameConnection=True`
2. Add Execute SQL Tasks to `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT TRANSACTION`, and `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`

See the following answer for more information:
[TransactionOption in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10281173/93306)