# The implementation of Transaction with out msdtc in the design pattern

Tags: t-sql, ssis, transactions, ssis-2012

The transaction has implemented as shows below.When executed it says there is no begin transaction and the whole package exe has been roll backed.

How to get this work with out changing the structure
[image]

After the execution

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this transaction setup to work with Microsoft DBMS - you have to specify *RetainSameConnection=true* in Connection Manager properties.
More details [on this approach with screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10281173/1010622).

Comment: This is the error                     [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "rollback transaction" failed with the following error: "The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: That is the point - you should have a transaction to commit. According to picture 2 - you do both commit and rollback after insert script. Commit was the first and cleared transaction, so Rollback has nothing to do and reported so in the error message. By using conditions on task flow you have to select either Commit or Rollback, but not both.

Comment: Hi,What is you  opinion on ssis transaction with out Msdtc.the question asked,yesterday