# SSIS Package stays in execution and doesn't finish execution nor gives an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have created a package which has multiple data flow tasks. It also includes BEGIN TRANSACTION as an *Execute SQL Task*

When package is called by another package, it doesn't finish execution. However, if it is run by hand, it executes successfully.

[Here is the screenshot of the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afEhW.jpg)

Comment: What do the SSIS logs say?

Comment: Also what does `sp_who2` say? SSIS logs and database connections are two tools that you can use when a package appears to be doing nothing. Also with regards to transactions, do you know about _RetainSameConnection_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702336/the-implementation-of-transaction-with-out-msdtc-in-the-design-pattern/37702624#37702624

Comment: OnProgress,WIN-H9FUIU6FDDC,WIN-H9FUIU6FDDC\UniAdmin,M_EC_SHOUHIN_SKITE_DETAILS_TEMP,{55BD8DCF-FB10-4B2D-8643-63BE04B0F619},{A9F5C321-2EA6-4A2B-A4E4-A13D0ED344B7},2018/09/10 23:35:47,2018/09/10 23:35:47,0,0x,実行前

OnProgress,WIN-H9FUIU6FDDC,WIN-H9FUIU6FDDC\UniAdmin,M_EC_SHOUHIN_SKITE_DETAILS_TEMP,{55BD8DCF-FB10-4B2D-8643-63BE04B0F619},{A9F5C321-2EA6-4A2B-A4E4-A13D0ED344B7},2018/09/10 23:35:47,2018/09/10 23:35:47,50,0x,Before execution

Comment: RetainSameConnection is true

Comment: OnProgress goes to 50 from 0, but not 100

Comment: I don't know what that step does, but If you run `sp_who2` in the database that the data flow is running against, do you see any locks?

Comment: I am sorry I don't know what sp_who2 is. I will google it. Thanks. I am a newbie

Comment: Those are the magic words!!! "I will google it"! That will take you a really long way. It's suprising how many people are unable to help themselves by googling - well done you'll go a long way with that attitude. Post back if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a local task after calling a child package.
In other words, the call package task shouldn't be the last task in the main package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).