# SSIS Execute Process Task Stays In Execuion

Tags: postgresql, ssis, etl, plpgsql, ssis-2012

I have package which has Execute Process Task. It calls C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\psql.exe. (postgresql)

It accesses pgpass.config file from C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\postgresql.

It runs smoothly without any hitches. However, when this package is called form another package (we call it engine) as SQLJob, the package stays in execution only. It doesn't throw any error either.

Comment: This usually means psql.exe is prompting for something. You need to isolate the cause - is it caused by running as a subpackage or is it caused by running from SQL Agent?

Comment: Is it related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268610/ssis-package-stays-in-execution-and-doesnt-finish-execution-nor-gives-an-error You need to pick the complexities out of it (transactions, sub packages, SQL Agent) and work out what the cause is

Comment: it is not related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268610/ssis-package-stays-in-execution-and-doesnt-finish-execution-nor-gives-an-error

Comment: OK so next step is to run it _just_ in SQL Agent and also run it _just_ as a sub package and see which one causes the issue