# SSIS - I want the package to fail if there is error in Data Conversion transformation

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, data-conversion, ssis-2012

I am reading an CSV file and importing data into database. In my csv file there is an an ID field which is initially string. Using a data Conversion transformation I am changing the datatype of ID field to Int.

In case the ID is not an integer in at least one row, I want the whole package to fail and it should not process any records.

Data conversion I have set Fail component for for ID field but it still passes rest of the records which have valid ID.

I want the whole package to fail if any of the ID's are not valid, how can I achieve this please?

Example:

Input

```
ID | value
1  | apple
2  | Orange
3  | Kiwi
a4 | Black
a5 | Blue
```

As ID's a4 and a5 can not be converted to Int by Data conversion transformation, 
it should not process any records. but in DB table I get 1,2,3.

Answer (score 2):

The observed SSIS behavior is normal, please find an explanation below. SSIS reads and transforms data in batches, and writes the data to the destination in batches as well. So, if your package processed 3 first records fine and then found an error, the package will stop but inserted rows will remain.
What you can do about it? Answer is simple - use transactions! Either set **transactionlevel=required** on the dataflow task (if all your data manipulation is there), or use MS SQL transactions. Once the error will be fired - transaction will be rolled back, and you will get rid of the erroneous rows. The former approach requires MSDTC on both SSIS and Destination MS SQL servers and might be slower compared to the second. If you need to include several tasks into the same transaction - you need to put them to one *Sequence* and set **TransactionLevel** on the *Sequence*.
The second approach with MS SQL Transactions requires more complex task flow - to conditionally commit or roll back the transaction, setting **RetainSameConnection=true** on the MS SQL Destination Connection Manager ([see example with screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10281173/1010622)) etc.

Comment: Hi apologies for delayed response, In my data flow task, I am using a lookup transformation for Insert and Update records. Updating records are from the match Output of the Lookup. If I set transactionLevel = required on my dataflow task (I have tried it) The lookup transformation fails too which is not Ideal. Can i use Script task to loop through the ID field and only send the whole set of data if the IDs are all valid?

Comment: @Rao, you can do better. Create a buffer table, store there only valid records with transaction handling and then - read from it whit lookup etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered reading the entire content into a temporary table of some sorts and examine the content?

```
create table test
(
    id varchar(5),
    c1 varchar(500)
)

insert into test values (1, 'apple')
insert into test values (2, 'orange') 
insert into test values (3, 'kiwi')
insert into test values ('a4', 'black')
insert into test values ('a5', 'blue')

if (select COUNT(*) from test where ISNUMERIC(id) = 0) > 0
begin
    select 'bad values and let ssis package know'
end
```

Comment: I thought it was possible to do this is in SSIS package itself without writing it to am temp table.

Comment: You can - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to direct bad records to another path. You can then (as many developers do) save the error records and resolve them later and continue processing the valid data.

Of course you can set to fail on error in a transform instead of redirecting the errant rows. In the transform task click on 'Configure Error Output' (on your bottom left)  and you can decide if you want to ignore, fail component or redirect in case of an error.

Comment: I dont want to pass any records if there is one record with invalid ID field

Comment: I have tried Fail component as mentioned in my question. It passes the records which are valid int for ID and fails for invalid ID's. But I do not want to pass any records if there is an Invalid ID.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra data flow (temp) before the data flow, in the temp, load your csv to a temp table (temp table has the same structure as your real table), connect this new data flow to your data flow, the connection condition is successful, which means the loading temp table must be successful to continue to load the real table.